# REST HTTPS - PUT is not working as expected

Tags: xml, rest, api

I am new in REST HTTPS so my knowledge is little. I went thorough all docs for REST HTTPS and is not well explained in my opinion. I can get without any problem whatever I need however I cannot PUT/POST. Docs all it says is

> When HTTP PUT method is used for operations other than CRUD, the URL
>   specifies the required operation. This is also used to distinguish the
>   message from PUT method for update. The keyword "op" is included in
>   the URL as follows:
>
> Rest/{package}/{ObjectType}/op/{operation}
>
> For example, /Rest/Identity/IdentityGroup/op/query

GET  https://10.42.9.140/Rest/Identity/User/name/requenaf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:user xmlns:ns2="identity.rest.mgmt.acs.nm.cisco.com">
    <description>name.surname@paddypowerbetfair.co.uk</description>
    <id>1745</id>
    <identityGroupName>All Groups:IS Networks</identityGroupName>
    <name>requenaf</name>
    <attributeInfo>
        <attributeName>Description</attributeName>
        <attributeValue></attributeValue>
    </attributeInfo>
    <attributeInfo>
        <attributeName>Email Address</attributeName>
        <attributeValue>name.surname@paddypowerbetfair.co.uk</attributeValue>
    </attributeInfo>
    <attributeInfo>
        <attributeName>Full Name</attributeName>
        <attributeValue>Name Surname</attributeValue>
    </attributeInfo>
    <attributeInfo>
        <attributeName>Real Name</attributeName>
        <attributeValue></attributeValue>
    </attributeInfo>
    <changePassword>false</changePassword>
    <created>May 04 2017 08:32:17</created>
    <dateExceedsEnabled>false</dateExceedsEnabled>
    <enablePassword>*******</enablePassword>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <lastLogin></lastLogin>
    <lastModified>Nov 14 2017 13:58:22</lastModified>
    <lastPasswordChange>Oct 31 2017 09:22:45</lastPasswordChange>
    <loginFailuresCounter>0</loginFailuresCounter>
    <password>*******</password>
    <passwordNeverExpires>false</passwordNeverExpires>
    <passwordType>Internal Users</passwordType>
</ns2:user>
```

PUT https://10.42.9.140/Rest/Identity/User/op/query

```
<attributeInfo>
    <attributeName>Email Address</attributeName>
    <attributeValue>name.surname@gmail.com</attributeValue>
</attributeInfo>

61000400XML Parsing Error: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"attributeInfo"). Expected elements are <{query.rest.mgmt.acs.nm.cisco.com}andFilter>,<{query.rest.mgmt.acs.nm.cisco.com}query>,<{query.rest.mgmt.acs.nm.cisco.com}simpleFilter>. NOT_AVAILABLENOT_AVAILABLEBAD_REQUEST
```

UPDATE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:query xmlns:ns2="query.rest.mgmt.acs.nm.cisco.com">
    <name>names</name>
    <attributeInfo>
        <attributeName>Email Address</attributeName>
        <attributeValue>name.surname@gmail.com</attributeValue>
    </attributeInfo>
</ns2:query>

61013400Query page number should be no less than 1.SEARCH_BY_QUERYUserBAD_REQUEST
```

Comment: What makes you think we know anything about this REST API that you're trying to use? You have to tell us what it is (link to documentation, etc.). It clearly expects a specific XML format and is showing an error because you're not sending the XML it expects.

Comment: So it looks like you're using some kind of Cisco API. [This page](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/net_mgmt/cisco_secure_access_control_system/5-4/sdk/acs_sdk/rest.html) includes a sample of the XML format that you would send to the /query endpoint and it looks nothing like what you have there. Where did you get that XML format that you're trying to use?

Comment: I have already looked at that doc and as I said is not clear to me.

Comment: Why do you think this API is RESTful? Because it is accessible via HTTP/S? Just because it markets itself as such? If I cross-check against [these guidelines](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven) I see so many violations ...

Comment: That was the most useless answer I ever got.